# Eventlistener for http request response

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I need an eventlistener to notify the user of the status of their resquest to the API.

```
        switch (category) {
            case 'B':
                console.log('creating basis');
                break; 
            case 'B-T':
                console.log('creating basis top');
                kladdService.create_B_T(order); 
                break;
            case 'B-M-T':
                console.log('creating basis, mellom, top');
                kladdService.create_B_M_T(order); 
                break; 
            case 'B-M-M-T':
                console.log('creating basis');
                kladdService.create_B_M_M_T(order);
                break;

            case 'Mix_Minimum2B-M-T':
                kladdService.create_Mix_Minimum2B_M_T(order); 
                break;
            case 'Mix_Minimum2M-T':
                kladdService.create_Mix_Minimum2M_T(order); 
                break; 
        }
        console.log('order ble sent: '); 
        console.log(order); 
        //trenger en if her som venter på en http 200 response
        var url = 'http://localhost:32605/api/Kladd/' + category;
        console.log(url);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log(xhr.status); // 0 so either unsendt or opened
        logService.info('prduktet har fått en ID'); 
    };
```

The switch case works fine, but the status of the processed create method is only visible from the network panel in devtools.

I'm assuming I need the xhr variable, and based on xhr.status notify the user of the result.

Here is the output from the network panel in devtools

[image: info from network panel]

Comment: Have you tried doing anything like `xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){}` and checking the readyState and status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the id varaible returned from `kladdService` service i got the desired result:

```
     switch (category) {
            case 'B':
                console.log('creating basis');
                break; 
            case 'B-T':
                console.log('creating basis top');
                $scope.produktKladdId = kladdService.create_B_T(order); 
                break;
            case 'B-M-T':
                console.log('creating basis, mellom, top');
                $scope.produktKladdId = kladdService.create_B_M_T(order); 
                break; 
            case 'B-M-M-T':
                console.log('creating basis');
                $scope.produktKladdId = kladdService.create_B_M_M_T(order);
                break;

            case 'Mix_Minimum2B-M-T':
                $scope.produktKladdId = kladdService.create_Mix_Minimum2B_M_T(order); 
                break;
            case 'Mix_Minimum2M-T':
                $scope.produktKladdId = kladdService.create_Mix_Minimum2M_T(order); 
                break; 
        }
        console.log(order); 

        if ($scope.produktKladdId) { // if this is not defined, an error appears
            console.log($scope.produktKladdId); 
            logService.info('prduktet har fått en ID'); 
        } else {
            logService.error('noe gikk galt');
        }
```